# Creating a mask for a blur effect from a PS layer in After Effects

Tags: mask, adobe-after-effects

I importet a PS composition to Adobe After Effects and have trouble achiving to following effect.

I have a rendered Text Layer that I want to use to mask a gaussian blur effect.

The final effect should be that only the area within the Letters is blurred and nothing else (also with the sharp corners of the letters shapes).

I created a adjustment layer in after effects and applied a blur effect which blurs everything. I've tried to set the mask field to alpha and luma of the text shape layer, but for some reason it's not giving me the result I want, it makes everything look a little grey and mushy, but it's not the blur effect that I get when I turn the alpha/luma off.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are going for. I gave it a shot myself to see if I could do it, and came up with this: [Video link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23000764/BlurText.mov).

Here are the settings I used:

[image: AE settings]

I simply made an image with text and a transparent background in Photoshop, then used that image as an Alpha Matte for a duplicate background image. I then added Guassian Blur to the duplicate image.

Hope this helps! If you are going for a different look, post up an image of what you are trying to achieve.